# Using awk to get a specific string in line

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, ps

I have a java process containing multiple strings in the `ps` output. I just want a particular string out of it.

For example, I have

```
root 5565 7687  0 Nov20 ?  00:00:54 /bin/java -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m  -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dstdout.file=/tmp/std.out -da -Dext.dir.class=profiles/ -Dprocess.name=java1 -Djava.security.policy=security.policy
```

I want just want `process.name=java1` and require nothing else from the `ps` output. I was unable to find a tangible way to do so using awk or sed.

I am tried to use:

```
ps -ef | grep java1 | grep -v grep | awk '/process.name/ {print $0}'
```

The output I get is the `ps -ef` out.

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: The simplest way to get the output you want is to do `echo "process.name=java1"`. I doubt if that's useful but it's no less useful than what you have so far told us you want to do with 2 greps and an awk script. So, if you can update your question to tell us what it is you REALLY are trying to do, we can help.

Comment: @EdMorton, the question was as specific and detailed as it could get. How would you suggest the question to be edited? Considering the replies I got, I would say the question itself was fine, your ability to understand is not as much. And just so you know, the two greps are very common and the awk was an example of what I tried. Please think before you comment and vote.

Comment: I completely agree with what @Ed Morton said. Many people answered (me included) because we interpreted your question in a way. As we can see from your comments in each one of them, nothing worked to you but one. So this clearly states how poorly explained the question is... and how fast we answer without asking more details.

Comment: I didn't vote. You got answers that produce the output you want from some specific input - that is just the starting point for a solution. The answer you selected, for example, will fail given some `ps -ef` output. Consider what you posted - you did `grep java1 | awk '/process.name/'` and said you wanted a script to output `process.name=java1`. THINK about that. You never said what you really wanted to do at all, nor did you provide truly representative sample input or expected output so you left us all just guessing and most people apparently guessed wrong.

Comment: @EdMorton, fedorqui Now that you mention it, based on the answers, my question can be better formed. When I framed it, I was just not aware as to how to make it better. Basically I assumed too much. Don't get me wrong, everyone here has my gratitude for taking the time to help me out but as I mentioned, when I formed the question, it looked perfectly understandable.

Comment: Thats fine but to be clear the answer you selected almost certainly does NOT do what you really want since it is doing a "special" type of regexp match called a field separator match on the input string and will match against parts of longer strings. It MIGHT be what you want but that seems extremely unlikely as it makes no sense to want that. All of the other answers you've got so far have similar issues. Just because it looks like what you think you want and produces the output you want from one sample input string doesn't mean it's the right answer and won't bite you later with other input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
ps -ef | awk -F"process.name" '{split($2,a," ");print FS a[1]}'
process.name=java1
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler way: use `grep -o`

```
ps -ef | grep -o 'process.name=java1'
```

However that will only output the string "process.name=java1" (possibly multiple times, once for each process) which to me seems a little pointless. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I the only common factor between multiple processes is process.name. Java$x are amongst the many that get created.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this :

```
ps -ef | grep -o 'process\.name=[a-z0-9]\+'
```

Comment: This worked very very but I was hoping to use awk. Thank you very much for your response!

Answer (score 0):

Using `gnu-awk`:

```
ps -ef | awk -v s='process.name=' 'BEGIN{RS=s} !RT{print s $0}'
process.name=java1 -Djava.security.policy=security.policy
```

Comment: I needed everything after the `process.name`. With this I got back just 1. I have multiple processes with the `process.name=java$x` form. Thank you tho.

Answer (score 0):

This MIGHT be what you want but without more sample input (`ps -ef` output) and a better description of what it is you want to match after the `=` sign it's just one more guess:

```
$ sed -r 's#.*[[:space:]]+-D(process\.name=[^[:space:]]+).*#\1#' file
process.name=java1
```